# It takes 2 clicks to my signup to createAccount() (even though there's no mistakes and I changed nothing between clicks)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am filling my inputs correctly adhering to all rules. I typed the email format, username is not blank, and the password/confirmPassword match each other and follow the constraints. Therefore I would like to successfully do my post request on the first click to sign up, but unfortunately I get the alert "Please correct errors (marked red)" located in my handleSignUp() that I was hoping would only pop up when there is an actual mistake (emailOk === false, passwordsOk === false, or usernameOk === false). After I click ok on the alert and click sign up again WITHOUT changing the inputs, I don't get the alert about mistakes and can create the account. So it seems that the states of my inputs are taking a while to be accurate, or maybe it is something else.. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? (In the first set of console.logs in handleSignUp(), they all appear as false still during that first click)

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import InputAdornment from '@mui/material/InputAdornment';
import Visibility from '@mui/icons-material/Visibility';
import VisibilityOff from '@mui/icons-material/VisibilityOff';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import {StyledFilledInput} from './Signup.styles';
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

import globalContext from './globalContext';

const SignupForm = () => {
  const {signupOpen} = React.useContext(globalContext);
  const {setSignupOpen} = React.useContext(globalContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
    showPassword: false,
  });

  const [emailOk, setEmailOk] = React.useState(false);
  const [passwordsOk, setPasswordsOk] = React.useState(false);
  const [usernameOk, setUsernameOk] = React.useState(false);
  const [clickedSignup, setClickedSignup] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setSignupOpen(false);
    setClickedSignup(false);
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setValues({
      username: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      confirmPassword: '',
      showPassword: false,
    });
    setEmailOk(false);
    setUsernameOk(false);
    setPasswordsOk(false);
    handleClose();
  };

  const createUser = () => {
    try {
      console.log('inside createUser)');

        console.log('Creating user!');

        const param1 = values.username;

        const param2 = values.email;

        const param3 = values.password;

        const body = {username: param1, email: param2, password: param3};
        console.log(body);

      fetch('http://localhost:3010/v0/user', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(body),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        })
          .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
              throw res;
            }
            console.log('fetched post user');
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(body));
            navigate('/signedin');
            setSignupOpen(false);
            return;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            alert('User already exists');
          });
    } catch (e) {

    }
  };

  const handleSignUp = () => {
    const mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

    const pwd = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{7,15}$/;
    setClickedSignup(true);

    if ((values.email).match(mailformat)) {
      setEmailOk(true);
    }

    if ((values.username) !== '') {
      setUsernameOk(true);
    }

    if (values.password === values.confirmPassword &&
                  values.password.match(pwd)) {
        setPasswordsOk(true);
    }

    console.log(emailOk);
    console.log(usernameOk);
    console.log(passwordsOk);

    if (values.email === '' || values.password === '' ||
      values.confirmPassword === '' || values.username === '') {
      alert('Fields cannot be empty');
    }
    else if (emailOk === false | usernameOk === false || passwordsOk === false) {
      console.log(emailOk);
      console.log(usernameOk);
      console.log(passwordsOk);
      console.log(values.email);
      console.log(values.password);
      console.log(values.username);
      alert('Please correct errors (marked red)');
    }
    else {
      console.log(emailOk);
      console.log(usernameOk);
      console.log(passwordsOk);
      console.log(values.email);
      console.log(values.password);
      console.log(values.username);
      createUser();
    }
  };

  const handleClickShowPassword = () => {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      showPassword: !values.showPassword,
    });
  };


  const handleMouseDownPassword = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
    setValues({...values, [prop]: event.target.value});
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog open={signupOpen} onClose={handleClose}>
        <DialogTitle style={{color: '#811010'}}>
          Welcome to the account sign up page</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText style={{color: '#3E76E9'}}>
            Please enter all fields:
          </DialogContentText>
          <div>&nbsp;</div>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="filled-adornment-password"
            style={{fontSize: 12, color: (usernameOk === false && clickedSignup === true)? 'red' : '#757575'}} >
            Username *</InputLabel>
          <StyledFilledInput
            required
            value={values.username}
            onChange={handleChange('username')}
            label="Username"
            placeholder="Username"
            fullWidth
            margin="dense"
          />
          <div>&nbsp;</div>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="filled-adornment-password"
           style={{fontSize: 12, color: (emailOk === false && clickedSignup === true)? 'red' : '#757575'}} >
            Email Address *</InputLabel>
          <StyledFilledInput
            required
            value={values.email}
            onChange={handleChange('email')}
            label="Email Address"
            placeholder="Email Address"
            fullWidth
            margin="dense"
          />
          <div>&nbsp;</div>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="filled-adornment-password"
           style={{fontSize: 12, color: (passwordsOk === false && clickedSignup === true)? 'red' : '#757575'}} >
            Password (length > 5 and contain a number) *</InputLabel>
          <StyledFilledInput
            id="filled-adornment-password"
            type={values.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
            value={values.password}
            onChange={handleChange('password')}
            placeholder="Password"
            fullWidth
            endAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton
                  aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                  onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                  onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                  edge="end"
                >
                  {values.showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            }
          />
          <div>&nbsp;</div>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="filled-adornment-password"
            style={{fontSize: 12, color: (passwordsOk === false && clickedSignup === true)? 'red' : '#6F6F6F'}} >
            Confirm Password *</InputLabel>
          <StyledFilledInput
            id="filled-adornment-password"
            type={values.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
            value={values.confirmPassword}
            onChange={handleChange('confirmPassword')}
            placeholder="Confirmed Password"
            fullWidth
          />
          <div>&nbsp;</div>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleCancel}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button onClick={handleSignUp}>Sign Up</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignupForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.
>
> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

In your code, you are setting state for each check i.e., email, username and passwords.

It is possible that React is holding all your set states in an async operation and continuing executing the rest of the handleSignUp function. Hence, the previous states of emailOk, usernameOk and passwordsOk is false and you are not able to create user for the first time.

By the time, you submit the form second time, the new states are updated and all variables are set to true and you are able to create user.

- Please use temporary local variables to hold the valid states of email, passwords and username. Use these variables every where and set the states in the final if and else parts.

```
  const handleSignUp = () => {
    const mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

    const pwd = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{7,15}$/;
    setClickedSignup(true);

    let eOk = false;
    let uOk = false;
    let pOk = false;
    if ((values.email).match(mailformat)) {
      console.log('eOk');
      eOk = true;
    }

    if ((values.username) !== '') {
      console.log('uOk');
      uOk = true;
    }

    if (values.password === values.confirmPassword &&
                  values.password.match(pwd)) {
                    console.log('pOk');
        pOk = true;
    } else {
      console.log('N pOk');
      console.log(values.password === values.confirmPassword);
      console.log(values.password);
      console.log(values.confirmPassword);
      console.log(values.password.match(pwd));
    }

    console.log(eOk);
    console.log(uOk);
    console.log(pOk);

    if (values.email === '' || values.password === '' ||
      values.confirmPassword === '' || values.username === '') {
      alert('Fields cannot be empty');
    }
    else if (eOk === false || uOk === false || pOk === false) {
      console.log(emailOk);
      console.log(usernameOk);
      console.log(passwordsOk);
      console.log(values.email);
      console.log(values.password);
      console.log(values.username);
      setEmailOk(eOk);
      setPasswordsOk(pOk);
      setUsernameOk(uOk);
      alert('Please correct errors (marked red)');
    }
    else {
      console.log(eOk);
      console.log(uOk);
      console.log(pOk);
      console.log(values.email);
      console.log(values.password);
      console.log(values.username);
      setEmailOk(eOk);
      setPasswordsOk(pOk);
      setUsernameOk(uOk);
      createUser();
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked.

Comment: Glad, I would help. Could you please accept it as answer :)